# MCMC code is very slow for even small steps

Tags: python, mcmc, markov, emcee

I have a problem with Python. My question is not about any problem in writing code.
I have a script that has been used many times before for my calculations and my published papers. It is MCMC or Markov Chain Montecarlo (EMCEE python package).
For this, we should choose the number of steps. When I set it for example 500 steps, my code works well and after 7 minutes prints the results. But when I set its steps for 1000 or more, it never prints the results even if after 4 hours.  and it should be considered 1000 steps is not very big. I used 90000 steps before with this code.

I use Windows 8.1, not Linux.
Could it be the problem with my Windows or anything else?
I really need to run again my script.

Thank you

Comment: You say you've used to be able to run it fine before but not anymore, so you need to explain what you have (or haven't changed) since. Have you changed computer, OS, data set, python version, library version, etc etc... There can be many potential issues.

Comment: NO, Nothing is changed. Just I did not use it for one year.

Comment: So you're running the script on the exact same data as a year ago?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Everything is completely the same as before. My laptop, Python and...  Just for my personal reason, I was away from programming for a year, and Now I don't understand why it is so slow

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for a script to change in performance so drastically unless something major was changed. And unfortunately, it's not possible for us to figure it out. Maybe look into their change log and report it as a bug (the library might have been accidentally updated). Or it could be that the script relied on obscure things from the OS so an OS update caused some issue (Windows 8 is quite old). Or you're using some data that's much more complex now than it was earlier, but just misremember? There are too many things that might cause this.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman So I think I should run it in a new laptop and new OS